# selenium button tag click by class name in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I want to click button by class name

```
<button class="_z8J">
    <i class="iconArrowRight"></i>
</button>
```

This what i already try on python :

```
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_z8J')
button.click()
```

It doesn't worked. I have tried many ways but none of them are working kindly suggest

Comment: what do you mean by it's not working. does it throw any error/exception or it's just not able to click without any error

Comment: IMO, you won't be able to click on this button tag (only) using `classname` locator. Thanks

Comment: is the class name constant? it looks like dynamic.

Comment: It throws exception.

It is constant name.